# What DataAnnotations to use for creating standard table layout?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I'm new to DataAnnotations and I'd like to go for a try on the "code first" approach.

Here's a basic structure of all my tables in the database:

**Entity table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Entities
  ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
  , Name NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LEN(Name) > 0)
  )
```

**Enum table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Enum
  ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY
  , Name NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LEN(Name) > 0)
  )
```

**m:n table:**

```
CREATE TABLE MyMN
  ( MyEntity INT REFERENCES Entities (ID)
  , MyEnum INT REFERENCES Enum (ID)
  --
  PRIMARY KEY (MyEntity, MyEnum)
  )
```

Which DataAnnotations would I need to apply to my following classes to fulfill ***all*** the constraint definitions mentioned above and to create a table structure like the above?

**Entity class:**

```
abstract class EntityBase
  { int ID;
    string Name;
  }

class Entity : EntityBase
  {
  }
```

**Enum:**

```
enum MyEnum
  {
  }
```

**Some m:n class:**

```
class MyMN
  { Entity MyEntity;
    MyEnum MyEnum;
  }
```

Please note: The above class definitions are just abstract samples with names demonstrating their technical purpose. They do not show class names "meaningful" to any application.

Answer (score 0):

see [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583)
and [the conventions used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962) to identify keys etc

In fact the whole site is worth a look if youre new to EF. ;-)